# Javascript synchronous loop, wait until it is finished?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, loops, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to implement this kind of logic in Javascript:

```
LOOP
    doStuff();
END
console.log("Stuff has been done");
```

I've managed to do  it this way:

```
var loop = function() {
    console.log("events");
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
console.log("loop is finished");
someOtherCodeGoesHere();
```

But it doesn't work. Well, it does, but "loop is finished" appears even before RAF is called. This whole code makes sense though, but it's not working as I want it to.

I've also figured out that I can make loop() return a callback function once a condition is met, but I don't want to enclose *someOtherCodeGoesHere();* inside it because it's not what I want. Let's say if I have 10 loops, I'd have a callback hell. I just want it to keep going with the code flow, like a plain GOTO if you will.

Any ideas are welcome! :)

Comment: Why the downvoting? I'm sorry to have hurt someone's zealot-y feelings on async JS, but it's better to let the question be rather than downvoting without knowing the reasons to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the window.requestAnimationFrame() method, but since you are passing a callback as its only parameter I assume it is an asynchronous function. This means that its invocation does not block the execution of the methods after it. There is no guarantee that the RAF method will call the callback you passed in before the console.log is called. Normally any logic you want to happen after an async method runs you should put in the callback. Dealing with callbacks can be a pain so libraries like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) can be a great help. Here is an example of how you might write this using the async lib. (This code is assuming you wanted an infinite loop due to the recursion your attempting in your code)

```
var loop = function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        console.log("events");
    });
}
async.forever(loop, function(err) {
    console.log(err); // Only gets called if an error occurs
});
```